# Save decimal values in SQlite3 with PHP

Tags: php, sqlite, prepared-statement

I'm populating an Ads Elements in a Sqlite Database with PHP.
By now everything goes fine, but I realize now that sometimes the Ad can have a decimal value, not just an integer. So, I modified my Sqlite structure of the price field from INTEGER to REAL and changed the bind value type in my PHP code, but the DB just fill the price values with 0.0000000000000.

Here's my PHP Code:

```
...
foreach ($ads as $advert) {
    ...
    $smtm = $bd->prepare("INSERT INTO ads (id, cat_id, supercat_id, price, oldprice, header, body, email, name, phone, date, image, hits, rating, promo_type, user_id, prov_id) VALUES (:id, :cat_id, :supercat_id, :price, :oldprice, :header, :body, :email, :name, :phone, :date, :image, :hits, :rating, :promo_type, :user_id, :prov_id)");
    $smtm->bindValue(':id', $final['id'], SQLITE3_INTEGER);
    $smtm->bindValue(':cat_id', $final['subcatid'], SQLITE3_INTEGER);
    $smtm->bindValue(':supercat_id', $final['cat'], SQLITE3_INTEGER);
    $smtm->bindValue(':price', $final['price'], SQLITE3_FLOAT); //Has to be decimal (8,2)
    $smtm->bindValue(':oldprice', $final['oldprice'], SQLITE3_FLOAT); //Has to be decimal (8,2)
    $smtm->bindValue(':header', $final['header'], SQLITE3_TEXT);
    $smtm->bindValue(':body', $final['body'], SQLITE3_TEXT);
    $smtm->bindValue(':email', $final['email'], SQLITE3_TEXT);
    $smtm->bindValue(':name', $final['nombre'], SQLITE3_TEXT);
    $smtm->bindValue(':phone', $final['phone'], SQLITE3_TEXT);
    $smtm->bindValue(':date', $final['date'], SQLITE3_TEXT);
    $smtm->bindValue(':hits', $final['hits'], SQLITE3_INTEGER);
    $smtm->bindValue(':promo_type', $final['promo_type'], SQLITE3_INTEGER);
    $smtm->bindValue(':image', $final['image'], SQLITE3_BLOB);
    $smtm->bindValue(':rating', $advert['average_rating'], SQLITE3_FLOAT);  //Has to be decimal (2,1)
    $smtm->bindValue(':user_id', $final['user_id'], SQLITE3_INTEGER);
    $smtm->bindValue(':prov_id', $final['prov_id'], SQLITE3_INTEGER);
    $smtm->execute();
    ...
}
```

And here's my Sqlite Structure:

[image: Sqlite3 Structure]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this comment](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php#119800) on the docs:

> When you use REAL type column on SQLite, your setting of pdo parameter
>   of bindValue() is PDO::PARAM_STR.
>
> ```
> $stmt->bindValue(':elapse_time', $e_time, PDO::PARAM_STR);
> ```

In your code, you can go with the SQLite *way*, [`SQLITE3_TEXT`](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3stmt.bindvalue.php):

```
$smtm->bindValue(':price', $final['price'], SQLITE3_TEXT);
```

Goes without saying, but do the same with the other ones ;)